# Why does svn diff not show differences between files shown by regular diff?

Tags: svn, diff

Is there a reason for `svn diff` not picking up the differences between two files, whereas regular `diff` shows the diff? I have a project, in trunk with vendor third party library. I updated the lib in `branch/vendor/lib/current`. Doing a `diff` between `version.php` in `trunk` and `vendor/lib/current` shows:

```
44,45c44,45
< $build          = '6218';
< $timestamp    = '2011-03-16 03:11pm';
---
> $build          = '6354';
> $timestamp    = '2011-05-31 03:07pm';
```

But the same diff with `svn diff` shows no ouptut. They do not have shared 'ancestry,' but I would have thought it would still show the diff. Does anyone have any idea of why `svn diff` behaves like this?

Comment: How do you perform `svn diff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you execute the [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) command is important here.  If all targets are working copy paths, then the default behaviour is to show any local changes, *for each file specified*, because this is the most common use case.

If you want to force SVN to compare the two WC files, you should use the --old and --new flags.  But plain old `diff` works too, as you've seen.

Comment: Yeah Zac!  muchas gracias amigo